# TIBCO BusinessWorks XPath union operator

Tags: xpath, tibco, businessworks

I don't fully understand the behaviour I'm seeing when using XPath union operator.

Having the following XML

```
<root>
    <foo>hello</foo>
    <bar>world</bar>
</root>
```

We get these results for different XPath expressions

- `(/root/foo | /root/bar)[1]`                   -> hello
- `(/root/foo | /root/bar)[last()]`              -> world
- `(substring(/root/foo, 2, 4) | /root/bar)[1]` -> ello
- `(substring(/root/foo, 2, 4) | /root/bar)[last()]` -> world

So far, they are intuitive results but...

- `(/root/foo | substring(/root/bar, 2, 4))[1]` -> **orld** (expected hello)
- `(/root/foo | substring(/root/bar, 2, 4))[last()]` -> **hello** (expected orld)

Is there a reason for results presented? Are these compliant with XPath 2.0 spec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TIBCO BusinessWorks is XPath 1.0 compliant only. Some XPath 2.0 functions are supported.
(source: FAQ1-7BXZE5 on http://support.tibco.com)

To answer your two questions:

- "Is there a reason for results presented?"

Yes. XPath 1.0 union results are unpredictable. A good rule: One should not rely on Union order in BusinessWorks, even for simple cases.

- "Are these compliant with XPath 2.0 spec?"

The results are not compliant with XPath 2.0 specification but your queries are evaluated with an XPath 1.0 engine.

Comment: If it's just XPath 1.0 compliant, then this question applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752666/xpath-1-0-order-of-returned-attributes-in-a-union

Answer (score 1):

No, the last two results are not compliant with the spec. It's a type error if an operand to the union operator is a string rather than a node, which is the case in your last two examples.

Comment: I suppose you mean the last four (they all have a substring function). If I understand well, the problem is the last four expressions shouldn't be allowed.