# How to optimize many importxml from the same website?

Tags: xpath, optimization, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet where rows are products and columns are information about these products (Material, Color, Price, ...).

These information are retrieved using the function IMPORTXML with the corresponding xpath query. In the following example, the column D is the URL of this product. These functions retrieve information (Glass, Color and Type) for the product on row 3:

```
=IMPORTXML(D3,"//table[@class='info-table']/tr[th/text()[contains(.,'Glass')]]/td")
=IMPORTXML(D3,"//table[@class='info-table']/tr[th/text()[contains(.,'Color')]]/td")
=IMPORTXML(D3,"//table[@class='info-table']/tr[th/text()[contains(.,'Type')]]/td")
```

For each product, there are around 10 columns that are retrieved and thus 10 different functions IMPORTXML for the same URL.

It works properly when there are few products but when there are too many products only some information is retrieved and the other cells stay frozen with the value "Loading...".

The only workaround I found is **manually** copy/pasting the retrieved values (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+Maj+v) and then some other cells are unblocked and start import the values. In the end, I need to do this for all cells and it takes a lot of time.

1. Why do I have cells that stay frozen in "Loading..."? Is there a limit imposed by Google?
2. Should I adapt my functions to optimize the process and if possible reduce the number of IMPORTXML functions?
3. Do you have a better solution than my time consuming workaround?
4. The xpath query is always very similar. Is it possible to use a list of predefined elements. And then use other Google Sheet functions to obtain the same result but with only one IMPORTXML function

For example:

```
=IMPORTXML(D3,"//table[@class='info-table']/tr[th/text()[contains(.,{'Glass', 'Color', 'Type'})]]/td")
```

Comment: I found that it is possible to transform several IMPORTXML into a single one using the character |. In addition, it is possible to use the function TRANSPOSE to have all the results on a single row.

For example:

    =TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(D1,"//table[@class='info-table']/tr[th/text()[contains(.,'Material')]]/td 
| //table[@class='info-table']/tr[th/text()[contains(.,'Glass')]]/td
| //table[@class='info-table']/tr[th/text()[contains(.,'Type')]]/td"))

However, information is not displayed in the correct order and some xpath returns several results. I cannot use INDEX in this situation..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by adapting the xpath query and using a combination of different Google Spreadsheet formulas.

1. It is possible to combine several xpath queries using the character |
2. To only get the first result, you can surround the xpath query by (YOUR_XPATH)[1]
3. The TRANSPOSE function will move the several results on the same row

For example:

```
=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(D2,"
(//table[@class='info-table']/tr[th/text()[contains(.,'Diameter')]]/td)[1] | 
(//table[@class='info-table']/tr[th/text()[contains(.,'Material')]]/td)[1] | 
(//table[@class='info-table']/tr[th/text()[contains(.,'Glass')]]/td)[1] | 
(//table[@class='info-table']/tr[th/text()[contains(.,'W/R')]]/td)[1] | 
(//table[@class='info-table']/tr[th/text()[contains(.,'Caliber')]]/td)[1] | 
(//table[@class='info-table']/tr[th/text()[contains(.,'Type')]]/td)[1]"))
```

By doing so, there is only one importXML per product.

Comment: OMG Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Romain Capron - For the above solution, how do you insert an empty row - in case where you have to skip a row or two? something like | " " |?

Comment: Hi @AlexShevyakov, I'm not sure to understand exactly what you mean. Can you create a new question and provide a small example? Then add a link to this new question here in the comments. It will be more convenient :-)

Comment: @RomainCapron - no problem, sorry for troubling.

Comment: @AlexShevyakov, don't worry :-) It's just that it will be much easier to work on a whole new question instead of staying confined to comments. Just add here a link to the new question when it's done. I'll do my best to help.

Comment: @RomainCapron great answer - is there a way to get the first child of a child? You have (your_XPATH)[1], but that returns 2 vertical cells for me. And things like (your_XPATH)[1][1] isn't working. Thoughts?

Comment: Hi @JackNapier, do you have a working example? The best would be to create a new question on StackOverflow to have a better visibility.

Comment: @RomainCapron This is great. The only problem i'm having is with image import. It shows me just one image (first image) instead of 5 or 10 results as per other text results which split bi itself in different cells. Any suggestion what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @JohnGrischam, to overcome this issue I work in two steps. First step is to retrieve all the URLs with a single IMPORTXML. Then, you can do what you want with these URLs. For example, I display the images using the function IMAGE(an_image_url) to display an image in a cell.

Comment: As a heads up, the order of list of xpath entries is unfortuantely not preserved using the [union operator "|"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752666/xpath-1-0-order-of-returned-attributes-in-a-union) - the results always come back in the order in the XML tree from top-to-bottom. Is there some other operator that preserves order?